# Types of parameters 'key' and 'key' are incompatible

Tags: javascript, angular, function, angular9

We have recently upgraded from angular 8 to 9 and started getting this error.

Argument of type '(value: any[], key: number) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CollectionIterator<any[], void, Dictionary<any[]>>'.
Types of parameters 'key' and 'key' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)

[image]

Below is the code where this error is occurring and I am currently unbale to solve this.

```
GetMessageFailedDashboard(): Observable<MessageFailedDashboardModel[]> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      this.messageSvc.getAll('GetMessageFailedDashboard', (resp: any) => {
        let result: MessageFailedDashboardModel[] = [];
        _.chain(resp)
          .groupBy(function (member) {
            return member.ErrorCode;
          })
          .each(function (value, key: number) {
            let item = new MessageFailedDashboardModel();
            item.IsShowDetail = false;
            if (key == 1) {
              item.ErrorDescription = `Email and/or Phone number are missing in ${value.length} Personnel(s).`;
              item.PersonnelName = value.map(v => v.PersonnelName);
            }
            else {
              item.ErrorDescription = `${value.length} error(s) when transmission in database.`;
            }
            result.push(item);
          }).value();

        observer.next(result);
        observer.complete();
      }, (error: any) => {
        observer.error(error);
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  }
```

Can anyone point out the fix to resolve this.

UPDATE!!

Before each function the group by use these param types

[image]

Comment: The compiler tried to tell you that `each` function requires a different function parameter signature. `each` needs `CollectionIterator<any[], void, Dictionary<any[]>>`, but you passed in `function (value, key: number){...}`.

Where is `each` implemented?

Comment: It is implemented in Api call where I am getting data and adding in array in each loop

Comment: Does `each` function actually accept `function (value, key: number) => void` as the parameter?

Comment: @skouch2022 not it doesn't but it was somehow working in angular version 8 now we have upgraded further so it started giving build error as the type is now necessary to be right otherwise above error comes

Comment: Angular uses TypeScript so we can leverage the type checking system. It's good that it breaks now. If you update your code to include what object is return from `groupBy(...)` function, and the implementation of the `each` function, we can investigate further.

Comment: @skouch2022 Ok well here is the screen shot what your looking for 
I have updated my answer please check

Comment: It seems like some third-party or internal tool you or your team invented. If it's an internal tool, you will need to talk to your team and find out who wrote this. The best approach is to update `each` function to accept what you want to pass in.

If it's a third-party library, please find out what it is and let us know. I personally never see these functions before.